# Animation UITableView Width Constraint

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, autolayout

Inside a sidebar menu view controller (based on SWRevealViewController), I'm using two tables to simulate two columns. So when user clicks on an option that has sub-options, the other table view controller loads them. (See Image)

[image: An option with sub-options]

Now the problem is that not all options in the first table actually has sub-options. Thus, I need to animate the first table (table with main options) so it takes full superview width ***when there is no sub-options to show*** on the other table. Only clicking on an option that has sub-options should animate the width so the two columns appear side by side. (See Images)

(Left: Intended behaviour, Right: Current behaviour)

[image: Intended behaviour]
[image: current behaviour]

The logic for showing sub-options and reloading tables are done and it's working perfectly. The only problem I have is with the animation. To animate the table widths I thought of setting the auto layout for the labels inside cells as follow: `H:|-8-Label-8-|, V:|-8-Label-8-|`, and for the both tables: `H:|LeftTable(LeftTableWidth)-0-RightTable|` with creating an outlet for the `LeftTableWidth` constraint. So when I need to animate them I do this:

> ```
> [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
> self.subTableWidthConstraint.constant = width;
> [UITableView animateWithDuration:0.45f
>                  animations:^{
>                      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
>                  }];
> ```

Now the table widths are getting correctly animated. However, the labels inside the cells are not being animated from the initial width values to the final values. Instead, their new values are immediately set, the moment the constraint gets changed (before the tables complete their animation). I've even tried to remove everything other than:

> ```
> self.subTableWidthConstraint.constant = width;
> ```

and they're still get their new values, without even call `[self.view updateConstraints]`.

So... any clue what I did wrong? 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out! Since I'm using RTL language, I needed to set the mode of the labels to `Right` instead of the default `Left` value.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with animation - layoutIfNeeded for all animation-related views in animation block helps me.

```
self.subTableWidthConstraint.constant = width;
[self.subTable setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[UITableView animateWithDuration:0.45f
                                            animations:^{
                                                [self.subTable layoutIfNeeded];
                                                [self.mainTable layoutIfNeeded];
                                                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                                            }];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the exact same behaviour still happens. Actually, whatever I add after 'self.subTableWidthConstraint.constant = width' has no effect at all to my issue. That line alone applies the change immediately for the cell labels. By the way, we're using the EXACT same variable names! XD